# Skip HTTP authentication with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, basic-authentication

I have a site where user must login to access. I have some web services calls for getting datas stored in another server.

But to access to the server user must login again via a login popup. To avoid this I want to pass the user/password but not in the URL.

Is it possible to do this in Javascript adding user/password in header or something similar ?

Comment: You should write a proxy in a server-side language to which you communicate using JavaScript. Otherwise the used password will be visible in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the W3C specifications for the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#open) Object. The five-parameter version of the 'open' method allow you to specify the username and password.

**EDITED**

Keep in mind: this will make your password publicly accessible.

Comment: Most JS libraries also provide convenient ways to specify login information, in case the OP is already using one

Comment: But keep in mind that this makes the password publicly accessible.

Comment: I use HTTPS requests.

Answer (score 1):

Authorization of this type is typically done via request headers. For regular users interacting with a web page, the login credentials may be remembered using the cookies in the request. For API access, however, the standard way to do this is with [bearer tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) included in the POST body of the request. See also: [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/).

For authenticating API access (but not the user), such authentication is typically done via API keys.

Important footnote: whenever doing any authentication, you should ensure that your requests are encrypted (and, when setting cookies, that cookies used for authentication are properly marked "secure").